# how to create a directory in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a directory on my server. Here is my code for one directory...

```
$path = "UserIds/";
$di = $path . $userid;

mkdir($di,0777);
```

It's work fine but here I need another directory.  Here is my code...

```
$dir="$di./".date("Y/m/d");

mkdir($dir,0777);
```

This does not make the directory. What is wrong?

Comment: Is that point in "$di./" required?

Comment: Here is $userid is my id and $di is above I create $di var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the quotation marks differently:

```
 $dir= $di . "/" . date("Y/m/d");
```

If you use PHP version > 5.0.0, maybe add a third parameter in your mkdir command: recursive ([as pointed out in the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)):

```
 mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it recursive by setting the third argument to `TRUE`.

```
mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE);
```